# Change a Postgres configuration value in Docker on Azure

Tags: postgresql, azure, docker, timescaledb

Our project uses TimescaleDB on PostgreSQL in Azure Container Instance. But when I change the settings, for example, `max_connections` in the var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf file, the value returns to the previous state after the reboot (I used vi editor to modify). I am building a container via Dockerfile.

```
FROM timescale/timescaledb:latest-pg12

ENV POSTGRES_USER=admin \
    POSTGRES_DB=timescaledb \
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test123# \
```

Is there some environment variable to set these values? What is the best way to store the database, is it is possible to transfer DB to the Azure Storage?

Answer (score 0):

If you are managing Dockerfile yourself, then you can fix modify `postgresql.conf` there. For example, add the following line in the Dockerfile, which will set `max_connections` to 100:

```
sed -r -i "s/[#]*\s*(max_connections)\s*=\s*0/\1 = 100/" /usr/local/share/postgresql/postgresql.conf.sample
```

Also I suggest to check [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/howto-configure-server-parameters-using-cli) on configuring PostgreSQL server. For example, to update `max_connections` server configuration parameter of server `mydemoserver.postgres.database.azure.com` under resource group `myresourcegroup` will be:

```
az postgres server configuration set --name max_connections --resource-group myresourcegroup --server mydemoserver --value 100
```